# Processing the collection concurrently in java

Tags: collections, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am using the following code fragment to process the java collection concurrently.
Basically i am using the TaskExecutors to process the collection in multiple threads that check for the duplicate transaction in the collection based on the transaction id. There is no relationship between the transactions except the duplicate check.

I want to know the following code has any concurrent issue?

```
public class Txn {
    private long id;
    private String status;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.getId() == ((Txn) obj).getId();
    }

}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Txn> list = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        List<Txn> acceptedList = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        List<Txn> rejectedList = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000l; i++) {
            Txn txn = new Txn();
            txn.setId(i % 1000);
            list.add(txn);
        }
        final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            final Txn txn = list.get(i);
            Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    if (map.putIfAbsent(txn.getId(), 1) != null) {
                        txn.setStatus("duplicate");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            executorService.submit(callable);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (Txn txn : list) {
            if (txn.getStatus() != null && txn.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("duplicate")) {
                rejectedList.add(txn);
            } else {
                acceptedList.add(txn);
            }
        }
        Set<Txn> set = new HashSet<>(acceptedList);
        if (set.size() != acceptedList.size()) {
            throw new Exception("11111111");
        }
        System.out.println(acceptedList.size());
        System.out.println(rejectedList.size());
    }
}
```

Appreciate your comments.
Thanks

Comment: First problem I see is that your callables are useless (negligible computations). Your algorithm won't be faster because you put it on multiple threads. If you want  to make good use of threads, split your whole collection of transaction into n smaller collections and distribute them on n threads.

Comment: @sturcotte06                                                        If i split in to multiple list(divide and concur), how can i check for the duplicate transaction? Please advise.

Comment: Make an intelligent split. Compute hashes for all transactions. Duplicates should compute to the same hash value. Split the collections on the hash range. This way, all duplicates will end up on the same thread.

Comment: @sturcotte06: If possible can you provide me any examples/articles for your suggestion. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses the divide and conquer method to split the list of transaction in to multiple small list and process each list in the separate thread and then merge the each partitioned list in to a single list.
As suggested by [sturcotte06](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584754/sturcotte06), need to override the hashCode method to keep the duplicate transactions in the same list.
The main advantage of this method is there is no race condition when using the HashMap.

```
public class MainDivideAndConquer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Txn> list = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        List<Txn> acceptedList = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        List<Txn> rejectedList = new ArrayList<Txn>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000l; i++) {
            Txn txn = new Txn();
            txn.setId(i % 1000);
            txn.setStatus("sadden");
            list.add(txn);
        }
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        int cpuCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final List<Txn>[] splittedArray = split(list, cpuCount);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpuCount);
        List<Future<List<Txn>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
            final List<Txn> splittedList = splittedArray[i];
            System.out.println("list size:" + splittedList.size());
            Callable<List<Txn>> callable = new Callable<List<Txn>>() {
                Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

                @Override
                public List<Txn> call() throws Exception {
                    for (Txn txn : splittedList) {
                        if (map.containsKey(txn.getId())) {
                            txn.setStatus("duplicate");
                        } else {
                            map.put(txn.getId(), 1);
                        }
                    }
                    return splittedList;
                }
            };
            futures.add(executorService.submit(callable));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
            Future<List<Txn>> future = futures.get(i);
            for (Txn txn : future.get()) {
                if (txn.getStatus() != null && txn.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("duplicate")) {
                    rejectedList.add(txn);
                } else {
                    acceptedList.add(txn);
                }
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken:" + (t2 - t1) / 1000000000);
        System.out.println(acceptedList.size());
        System.out.println(rejectedList.size());
    }

    public static List<Txn>[] split(List<Txn> transactions, int n) {
        List[] splitResult = new List[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            splitResult[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        for (Txn txn : transactions) {
            splitResult[txn.hashCode() % n].add(txn);
        }

        return splitResult;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a divide and conquer approach to make full use of parallelism. Have your transaction class extends hashCode():

```
public class Transaction {
    ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Not really good hash fucntion, but I don't know your object
        return this.id * 53 * 47 * 13;
    }
}


public class Transaction {
    ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Not really good hash fucntion, but I don't know your object
        return this.id * 53 * 47 * 13;
    }
}
```

Then make a method that will split the transactions based on the hascode of each transaction.
Because hashCode() should return the same value for equal objects, duplicates will end up in the same smaller collection:

```
public Collection<Transaction>[] split(Collection<Transaction> transactions, int n) {
    Collection<Transaction>[] splitResult = new Collection<Transaction>[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        splitResult[i] = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
        splitResult[transaction.hashCode() % n].add(transaction);
    }

    return splitResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sturcotte05. I will modify my program with this change and see i can achieve any improvement

Comment: @sturcotte05, I tried with divide and conquer method, it is looks like around 4 times faster than the method i used. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Very nice! Happy to have helped you.